# Latex editor for windows that works with unicode

Tags: latex, editor, text-editor

I need to write Hebrew text in Latex.
I am currently working on Windows with TeXnicCenter. I was pretty happy with this tool, up until the time when I needed to write Hebrew text. My regular alt-shift just won't change the language (I even downloaded the last alpha version, which was supposed to solve the problem, but it didn't).

So I'm looking for another latex editor for windows that will let me write Hebrew.

Please advice.

Note: I know that it is possible with Lyx, but I prefer a real Latex editor.

---

I found the solution to my problem, so I'm describing it here:

Apparently, I did not have the fonts for Hebrew. The Hebrew fonts can be downloaded here:
http://www.ma.huji.ac.il/~sameti/tex/culmusmiktex0.2.1.exe

After the download the compilation of latex to pdf works, but texniccenter did not just read the fonts. I managed to make it work in WinShell the following way:
    `Options -> Fonts -> (Documents, Tahoma Font, Hebrew, Standard Encoding)`

Thanks you for answering :-)

Comment: Use those "Evil Red Text" if you ever need to use LaTeX code within LyX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WinEdt doesn't suppose Unicode yet but it will in the next release. But you can consider WinShell. It's a very good LaTeX editor and you can find its features at:

http://www.winshell.org/modules/ws_features/

I've used it before and was happy with the forum support.

**Update**

March 21, 2012: [WinEdt 7](http://www.winedt.com/) now supports Unicode.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to those already mentioned, TeXniccenter v2 (currently in beta) and TeXworks are both natively Unicode TeX editors.

Comment: @Joseph, I downloaded the beta version of TeXniccenter, but the Hebrew does not work for me. In the compiled pdf I'm getting question marks.
Did you try working with it?

Comment: I have to confess that I'm not a TeXniccenter user myself, and I also don't speak Hebrew! I assume you did the compilation with XeTeX and a suitable font loaded?

Comment: Yes, I did the compilation with XeTex, but regarding the fonts, I'm not sure. It didn't have a description how and where I can load the suitable font, so it is possible that I don't have it. Hebrew is a right-to-left language, so it might be more problematic than many other languages :-/. I'll try to tweak it some more and try to find the loaded fonts, and update with results.

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse + [TexLipse](http://texlipse.sourceforge.net/) work pretty good for me

Otherwise TexEmacs